# Unity issues with Oculus OVRCamera and GUI Texture not visible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am trying to do a simple Fade to black using the OVRCamera Rig Shipped with the Oculus Unity Tools.

However, no matter what part of the rig (or all parts) the GUI Texture is assigned to, it doesn't show up in the headset. If I use the same scene but with Unity's standard Camera and Assign the GUI Component it works as expected (Even in the Headset). Any Ideas how to go about doing this?

(Latest Unity SDK From Oculus: OculusUtilities_0_1_2_beta)

Answer (score 0):

GUI is not rendered into the headset. (You don't say how you are rendering it - like in OnGUI, etc). If you want to use that fading technique I would use use a Canvas UI set to world-space or a plane as a child of the camera, positioned and scaled so it fills the whole FOV.

Comment: You Assign a GUI Texture to a component in Unity. In this case I have added one to every part of the OVRCamera and it sill doesn't render.Adding the GUI Texture to a standard Unity Camera works as intended... even in the headset.

Comment: I haven't ever tried to render a GUITexture component into the headset because it should be drawn to the GUI layer which is currently not working in VR (Unity 5.2.2p2). The way I know works is put a plane as a child of the camera, move it out a bit, and put your texture on that.